# How do i add a string say ohms to the list after the value in the list is printed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pycharm

> > option for the user switch case. if u want to run use the input 0, 1 ,3  for the option input cuz all the option value are not assigned yet for now

```
option1=input("Choose the First Colour\n"
              "0. Black\n"
              "1. Brown\n"
              "2. Red \n")
option2= input("Choose the Second Colour\n"
               "0. Black\n"
               "1. Brown\n"
               "2. Red\n")

option3=input(" Choose the Third color\n "
              "0. Black\n"
              "2. Brown\n"
              "3. Red\n")
Black, blue, red = 5, 4,7

    if option1 =='0':
        print(option2)
        a=[]
        a.append(Black)
    elif option1=='1':
        print(option2)
    else:
        print(option2)

if option2=='0':
    print(option3)
elif option2=='1':
    print(option3)
    a.append(blue)
else:
    print(option3)


if option3=='3':
    a.append(red)
    for item in range (0, len(a)):
        print(a[item], end="")
```

> > The output that this program gives is

```
547
```

> > the output that i need is

```
547 ohms
```

> > So help me to add string named "ohms" at the list after the value is printed
> >     Note : remember to use input 0,1,3 only for now if u are debugging the program.

Comment: You should store a dictionary of "colour -> number" for each resistor band. Calculating the total resistance from there is just a case of multiplying and adding values once you have the information

Comment: I got your point. However my doubt is on decision statement.The user has to choose three input colour from the switch case option  and has to satisfy all three at a time , then only the resistor value assigned will be calculated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you saying that you only want to perform the calculation of resistance **after** the user has input all three values? If this is on a web page, just set the default value to be black (0) on each field and perform the calculation from there. If the user has selected anything else, this will be reflected in the passed values accordingly

Comment: @DaveyBoy I somehow modified the code edited the question above and now i started  getting  the expected result.  Well its not complete yet. i think i might  need more lines of code. however can u plz add some more line to get the expected result... i need 547 ohms as an output  but it shows the output only 547. i need to add string "ohm" to last of the list after the integer is printed. since the code is not completed yet use the input 0,1,3 for switch case to run the code above for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a `print ohms` after the for loop.
like so:

```
if (option3=='3'):
 a.append(red)
 for item in range (0, len(a)):
    print(a[item],end="")
 print(" ohms")
```

The for loop can be written better,like:

```
if (option3=='3'):
 a.append(red)
 for item in a:
    print(item,end="")
 print(" ohms")
```

Or, add an item " ohms" to the list, ***before*** printing the list:

```
if (option3=='3'):
    a.append(red)
    a.append(" ohms")
    for item in a:
        print(item,end="")
```

Update: The question poster has added his own buggy code as an answer, and asked me to work through it! The code is all over the place and confuses the issue even more. I suggest that he reformulate the question in a clear way.
I guess he wants some kind of calculation for some electrical circuit problem, where the resistance values change according to the 3 positions and the color chosen.  Here's an update based on the detailed code in his "answer".

```
OptionS12 = {"0":1, "1":1, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, \
             "7":7, "8":8, "9":9}  # option1 and 2 according to the menu items above
OptionS3 = {"0":1, "1":10, "2":200, "3":3000, "4":40000, "5":500000, "6":6000000, \
            "7":70000000, "8":800000000, "9":9000000000}  # option 3 according to the menu items above
a = [] # my calculated outputs will be in this list
for option in [option1,option2]: # for each option
 if (option in OptionS12):
    print(option)
    a.append(OptionS12[option])  # add the value for that option from the color_codes dictionary of values
 else:
     print("option does not exist",option)
if option3 in OptionS3:
    print(option3)
    a.append(OptionS3[option3])  # add the value for that option from the color_codes dictionary of values
    if option3 in ["0","1","2"]:
        a.append(" ohms")
    elif option3=="3":
        a.append(" kilo ohms")
    else:
        a.append(" mega ohms")
else:
    print("option does not exist", option3)
for item in a:
    print(item,end="")
```

Comment: i have posted a modified code of line below in can u plz check and modify

Answer (score 0):

```
    option1 = input("Choose the First Colour\n"
                "0. Black\n"
                "1. Brown\n"
                "2. Red \n"
                "3. Orange\n"
                "4. Yellow\n"
                "5. Green\n"
                "6. Blue\n"
                "7. Violet\n"
                "8. Grey\n"
                "9. White\n")

option2 = input("Choose the First Colour\n"
                "0. Black\n"
                "1. Brown\n"
                "2. Red \n"
                "3. Orange\n"
                "4. Yellow\n"
                "5. Green\n"
                "6. Blue\n"
                "7. Violet\n"
                "8. Grey\n"
                "9. White\n")

option3 = input("Choose the First Colour\n"
                "0. Black\n"
                "1. Brown\n"
                "2. Red \n"
                "3. Orange\n"
                "4. Yellow\n"
                "5. Green\n"
                "6. Blue\n"
                "7. Violet\n"
                "8. Grey\n"
                "9. White\n")

Black, Brown, Red, Orange, Yellow = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Green, Blue, Violet, Grey, White = 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
################################################
if option1 == '0':
    print(option2)
    a = []
    a.append(Black)
elif option1 == '1 ':
    print(option2)
    b = []
    b.append(Brown)
elif option1 == '2':
    print(option2)
    c = []
    c.append(Red)
elif option1 == '3':
    print(option2)
    d = []
    d.append(Orange)
elif option1 == '4':
    print(option2)
    e = []
    e.append(Yellow)
elif option1 == '5':
    print(option2)
    f = []
    f.append(Green)
elif option1 == '6':
    print(option2)
    g = []
    g.append(Blue)
elif option1 == '7':
    print(option2)
    h = []
    h.append(Violet)
elif option1 == '8':
    print(option2)
    i = []
    i.append(Grey)
elif option1 == '9':
    print(option2)
    j = []
    j.append(White)


####################################

if option2 =='0':
    print(option3)
    a.append(Black)
elif option2 == '1 ':
    print(option3)
    b.append(Brown)
elif option2 == '2':
    print(option3)
    c.append(Red)
elif option2 == '3':
    print(option3)
    d.append(Orange)
elif option2 == '4':
    print(option3)
    e.append(Yellow)
elif option2 == '5':
    print(option3)
    f.append(Green)
elif option2 == '6':
    print(option3)
    g.append(Blue)
elif option2 == '7':
    print(option3)
    h.append(Violet)
elif option2 == '8':
    print(option3)
    i.append(Grey)
elif option2 == '9':
    print(option3)
    j.append(White)

#############################

if option3=='0':
    a.append('')
    a.append(' ohms')
    for iteml in range (0, len(a)):
        print(a[iteml], end="")
elif option3=='1':
    b.append('0')
    b.append(' ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(b)):
        print(b[item], end="")
elif option3=='2':
    c.append('00')
    c.append(' ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(c)):
        print(c[item], end="")
elif option3 =='3':
    d.append('000')
    d.append(' Kilo ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(d)):
        print(d[item], end="")
elif option3=='4':
    e.append('0000')
    e.append(' Kilo ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(e)):
        print(e[item], end="")
elif option3=='5':
    f.append('00000')
    f.append(' Mega ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(f)):
        print(f[item], end="")
elif option3=='6':
    g.append('000000')
    g.append(' Mega ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(g)):
        print(g[item], end="")
elif option3=='7':
    h.append('0000000')
    h.append(' Mega ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(h)):
        print(h[item], end="")
elif option3=='8':
    i.append('00000000')
    i.append(' Mega ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(i)):
        print(i[item], end="")
if option3=='9':
    j.append('000000000')
    j.append(' Mega ohms')
    for item in range (0, len(j)):
        print(j[item], end="")
```

> > The problem here in this code above is  that i can't calculate different resistor colour code. say i want to calculate *RED YELLOW BLUE,* it gives error..cuz all are not append in same list; while say if i calculate same colour code *RED RED RED* from option input  it can be calculated. In fact there is a mistake in append line cuz all the value are append in one list but for calculating different colour code it need to pass the value to some other list from different option. Can u run and modify the program to calculate different colour code of resistor.

Comment: @Contrarian. Above